# how can i shwo values of database columns on telegram bot php?

Tags: php

**I made a code but it's not working it's showing this message `Array ['premium']` instead of data....**
*my code:-*

```
if(strpos($message, "/values") === 0){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM info";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    
sendMessage($chatId, "<b> $row ['premium'] </b>", $message_id);
}
}
```

Comment: `$row['premium']` without the extra space.

Comment: i have getting syntax error when i doesn't put space..

Comment: Try `"<b> {$row['premium']} </b>"`